# Upper bound for smallest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for a (simple) upper bound for the smallest eigenvalue of an $n\times n$ matrix, involving determinant or trace or something else that can be easily computed. I've got an upper bound from the $nth$-root of the determinant, but need a little improved bound.

In the original post, I forgot to say that the matrix is symmetric and positive definite.

Any ideas would be welcome,

Thanks

Comment: This maybe useful for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: Be careful: if the balls from the Gershgorin circle theorem overlap, it won't be of much use.  By the way, if your matrix is $A$, if you plug in **any** vector $x^T A x$, that is an upper bound on the smallest eigenvalue. Not sure what use that is to you, but knowing more about the matrix might suggest simple vectors to test. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem for reference.

Comment: You can get bounds on the roots of the characteristic polynomial using this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_.28complex.29_polynomial_roots

Comment: I understand how trace is simple, but computing the determinant has about the same $n^3$ complexity as computing the eigenvalues or inverting the matrix, so I do not see any gain here.

Comment: Frobenius norm and trace are two trivial uppper bounds.